# Datalist display items based on file names

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

This question to related to a similar `Data list` question I posted some days ago. I have a datalist which displays Categories, and then documents within categories. What needs to happen is that documents under each category gets displayed in the order based on some numbers in file names. Documents are in format like '001-filename.pdf', '002-filename.pdf' ... '00x-filename.pdf'. I can use the first dash as some kind of 'split' function then grab the numbers like '001' etc to make the sorting to work. I think this could be done on either `itemdatabound` or in the sql syntax. I am posting the relevant code here. Any idea as to how I can make this to work? It is possible that there could be more than one document with shared number prefix: '001-filename.pdf', '001-filenameversion2.pdf' etc. Thanks!

### ASPX:

```html
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" DataKeyField="docid"
    EnableViewState="True" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_data">
            <tr runat="server" id="tr_category">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname") %>'
                        Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_cb_all">Select All
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                            ID="cb_selectall" />
                    </asp:Label>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCatID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDocID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="tr_data">
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb_docid" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' OnCheckedChanged="displayselectedinit"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_docfileencr" Text='<%# Eval("docfileencr") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDFEncr/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "docfileencr") %>'
                        Target="_blank" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

### C# CodeBehind:

```c#
sqlsyntax = @"SELECT  dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr,dbo.categories.catid, dbo.categories.categoryname, dbo.projectsdocuments.docid
              FROM dbo.Projects INNER JOIN dbo.projectsdocuments ON (dbo.Projects.projectid = dbo.projectsdocuments.projectid)
              INNER JOIN dbo.categories ON (dbo.projectsdocuments.categoryid = dbo.categories.catid)
              WHERE  Projects.projectid = " + projectid + " ORDER BY dbo.categories.sortorder ASC";

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        var view = row.DataView;
        var lastRow = e.Item.ItemIndex == 0 ? null : view[e.Item.ItemIndex - 1];
        var tr_category = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("tr_category");
        var sameCategory = lastRow != null && (int)row["catid"] == (int)lastRow["catid"];
        tr_category.Visible = !sameCategory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't sort by both Category & File Name in your SQL ?  If you do this, you should get all your files in the order needed.

Comment: Oh, that would be easier. Thought about it but don't know the syntax of double sort. Let me see...

Comment: ahh! Sounds like a simple fix: changed the Order by to: ORDER BY dbo.categories.sortorder ASC, dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr ASC and it looks fine. I just hope it doesn't mess up the order by categories.sort order; not sure which of this would precedence in the Order by? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ORDER BY to include both columns.

```
SELECT  
    dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr,
    dbo.categories.catid, 
    dbo.categories.categoryname, 
    dbo.projectsdocuments.docid
FROM dbo.Projects 
INNER JOIN dbo.projectsdocuments 
    ON (dbo.Projects.projectid = dbo.projectsdocuments.projectid)
INNER JOIN dbo.categories 
    ON (dbo.projectsdocuments.categoryid = dbo.categories.catid)
WHERE  Projects.projectid = " + projectid + "
ORDER BY dbo.categories.sortorder, dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr
```

The order by precedence is left to right, the default is "ASCENDING" but you can change a specific column sort by adding "ASC or DESC" directly after it.

** IMPORTANT NOTE **

Your code is susceptible to **SQL Injection** because your doing string concatenation.  If this is a concern to you, change the SQL statement to use a named parameter that you assign using a command parameter (see example below).

**Step 1:**  Change the inline string parameter, to a named parameter "@projectid".

```
SELECT  
    dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr,
    dbo.categories.catid, 
    dbo.categories.categoryname, 
    dbo.projectsdocuments.docid
FROM dbo.Projects 
INNER JOIN dbo.projectsdocuments 
    ON (dbo.Projects.projectid = dbo.projectsdocuments.projectid)
INNER JOIN dbo.categories 
    ON (dbo.projectsdocuments.categoryid = dbo.categories.catid)
 WHERE  Projects.projectid = @projectid
 ORDER BY dbo.categories.sortorder, dbo.projectsdocuments.docfileencr
```

**Step 2:**  Assign the parameter inline (example code)

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    // Assign the value projectid to the parameter @projectid
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@projectid", projectid));

    // Execute The Command (fill dataset, create datareader, etc...)
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Zachary: Thank you very much! But would the SQL Injection still apply even if I have projectid = Convert.ToInt32(Request["projectid"]); ?

Comment: It shouldn't... but you could have an error thrown if something other than a Int is provided.